# MVC EF Reverse Engineer Code First primary key column/member missing from views in auto-generated code

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, primary-key, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am using an EF Reverse Engineer Code First project.  Specifically, I used the Entity Model, code first from database method that allows one to select only a subset of the database tables for a particular MVC project.

The primary key column/member for one of my table models *is* present in the table model, but when I auto-generated the views from the controller the primary key column/member is missing, except from the Create View.

Is this standard behavior for the new version 6 -- Visual Studio Entity Framework Tools or did I do something wrong?

If it is standard behavior, is there way to modify a setting so that the primary key column is present in the views?

Comment: I just redid it from scratch and the primary key is not present in the views, except the create view...  This is what some people want, in my case, the primary key is a string that is worth displaying.  I know how to modify the project to do this after-the-fact, but it would be nice if one could modify a setting to do this "out-of-the-box".  Any thoughts on this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Many people seem to think it is a good thing to hide primary keys.  Certainly in an internet context it would make sense.  My application is an intranet application where staff would be handling the data ....