# EF database first code generation missing Key and data annotation

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

For EF 6.1 and above, when I add/*reverse engineer-Entity model model/code generation* in VS15 & Sql-Server 2k16 Database *my entities are missing both Id, and auto increment data-annotations*. [Saw this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987745/mvc-ef-reverse-engineer-code-first-primary-key-column-member-missing-from-views) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777448/entity-framework-reverse-engineering-code-first-missing-the-foreign-key-relatio) Question on SO, but no answers, just that its a bug, I am seeking an option to generate the PK Key, Auto Increment.

Question: **How can I ensure, that the Id key & Auto-increment options are added to the entities** *during the code generation*? There are no data annotations except on the foreign keys! Can I also get EF to generate Composite keys?

**What I did**: 
In the database, I added the Set primary key on the `[Id]` col as `int`, 
I also set `Identity true`, `seed 1`, `auto increment 1`

E.g. missing primary key

---

```
//E.g. Reverse Eng. Generated code from ASP table 
public partial class AspNetUsers
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public AspNetUsers()
    {
        this.AspNetUserClaims = new HashSet<AspNetUserClaims>();
        this.AspNetUserLogins = new HashSet<AspNetUserLogins>();
        this.AspNetRoles = new HashSet<AspNetRoles>();
    }
    // Missing Primary Key
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdNumber { get; set; } ...
```

---

E.g. 2 **Missing both Primary Key & Auto Increment**

```
public partial class AuditNetEvent
{
    //Reverse Generated code missing Primary Key & Auto Increment
    public bigint Id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime InsertedDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: When I reverse engineer my database into code first classes, it creates the POCO classes without annotations and a model class with the context, dbsets and fluent code (OnModelCreating) to define the keys, relationships, etc. for all the selected tables.

Comment: @SteveGreene if I understand correctly, this is default behavior, correct? I checked in the `DbMode.Context`  it creates the sets fine, but no keys `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }` - how do I get it in there?

Comment: I have tweaked the [code generation templates](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.CodeTemplates.CSharp/) as described [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2241).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the tooling doesn't add annotations when the default conventions make them redundant. For an `Id` column the default is that it's PK and identity. I tried with a table not matching the conventions (deviating PK column name and no identity) and the annotations were added:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int CstId { get; set; }
```

Comment: ohh great, :) after all the searching it turnout convention over configuration! guess I should be glad. I reckon `Id` makes sense as a Pk ID, however, do all ID cols come with by default `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` thanks. will mark you as answer!